# Order preserving maps

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Suppose $f:X \to Y$ is order preserving. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. 
Does is follow that if $A$ is well ordered then $f(A)$ is well ordered?

Comment: The only thing mentioned is that it is order preserving

Comment: The problem is that *order-preserving* has several different possible meanings. However, I realized after I asked the question that the answer to your question is *yes* for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $S$ is a nonempty subset of $f[A]$, let $T=\{x\in A:f(x)\in S\}$. Then $T$ has a least element $t$, and $f(t)$ is clearly minimal in $S$.

Comment: T has a minimal is true but how can you say that f(t) is the minimal of S ?

Comment: @user81883: Because if $s\in S$, then $s=f(x)$ for some $x\in T$; $t\le x$, and $f$ is order-preserving, so $f(t)\le f(x)=s$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Comment: @user81883: You’re welcome.